# Delete certain files from a directory using regex regarding their file names

Tags: python, regex

Here I am making attempts to create a code what would delete files in a folder according to the mask. All files what include 17 should be removed File name format is ??_????17*.*, where ? - Any symbol 1..n,A..z, _ and 17 - are in any files (others contain 18, as well) and its extension doesn't matter. Certain example of a file AB_DEFG17Something.Anything - Copy (2).txt

```
import os
import re

dir_name = "/Python/Test_folder"         # open the folder and read files
testfolder = os.listdir(dir_name)

def matching(r, s):                      # condition if there's nothing to match
match = re.search(r, s)
if match:
return match.group()
return "Files don't exist!"

matching(r'^\w\w\[_]\w\w\w\w\[1]\[7]\w+\[.]\w+', testfolder)  # matching the file's mask

for item in testfolder.index(matching):
if item.name(matching, s):
os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))

# format of filenames not converted :  ??_????17*.* 
# convert for python separarately   :  [\w][\w][_\w][\w][\w][\w]\[1]\[7][\w]+[\.][\w]+
# ? - Any symbol 1..n,A..z \w repeating is * 
# * - Any number of symbols 1..n, A..z
# _ and 17 - in any files `
```

There are a few mistakes, as well.

> File "D:\Python\Test_folder\Remover v2.py", line 14, in 
>     matching(r'\w\w[_]\w\w\w\w[1][7]\w+[.]\w+', testfolder) # matching the file's mask
>   ￼ File "D:\Python\Test_folder\Remover v2.py", line 9, in matching
>     match = re.search(r, s)
>   File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE Personal 6.0\bin\runtime-python2.7\Lib\re.py", line 146, in search
>     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

I'm a beginner and with amateurish approach would like to get experience in PY, parallel learning details. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be useful. Thx

Comment: The shell already supports removing files by wildcard. Your regex does not seem to correspond to the glob wildcard in your problem statement particularly closely anyway. Python's `glob` module would probably be a better choice here.

Comment: For Python questions, you *must* make sure your indentation is correct. Having us guess which errors are actual errors in your code as opposed to problems caused by sloppy copy/paste is a waste of everybody's time. Try pasting your code as a single block, then selecting that block with the mouse, and typing ctrl-k to indent as code. (This doesn't appear to work in the mobile version of this site.) See also [help](/help/formatting).

Comment: `1`, `7`, and `_` just match themselves, there is no reason to put them in a character class. The backslash before `[` in your attempt turns it into *not* a character class anyway.

Comment: Having `matching` return a string in case of no match seems like a particularly bad choice. If you really think this needs to be a separate function, have it return something which is easy to handle in your other code, like `None` or `False`, and only use human-friendly representations when communicating directly with the uer.

Answer (score 8):

Don't reinvent the wheel, rather use [**`glob()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) instead:

```
import os
from glob import glob

for file in glob('/Python/Test_folder/AB_CDEF17*.*'):
    os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

```
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname, "AB_CDEF17*.*")):
    try:
        # Trying to remove a current file
        os.remove(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
    except EnvironmentError:
        # You don't have permission to do it
        pass
```

Using [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) and [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match)

```
pattern = re.compile(r"AB_CDEF17\w+\.\w+")
for filename in os.scandir(dirname):
    if pattern.match(filename):
        try:
            os.remove(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
        except EnvironmentError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command directly from your shell:

```
cd $PATH; for inode in $(ls -il AB_CDEF17*.* | awk '{print $1}'); do find . -type f -inum $inode -exec rm -i {} \;; done
```

- `cd $PATH;` go to the folder in question
- `$(ls -il AB_CDEF17*.* | awk '{print $1}')` will print all the inumbers of the files in your current directory, I am using this detour **since it looks like there are spaces inside the filenames**, therefore `rm` command will not work properly on them.
- `find . -type f -inum $inode -exec rm -i {} \;;` find the files based on their inumber and delete them by asking you permission.

if you are sure about what you do and you really want to embed it in some python code:

```
from subprocess import call
call('cd $PATH; for inode in $(ls -il AB_CDEF17*.* | awk '{print $1}'); do find . -type f -inum $inode -exec rm -f {} \;; done')
```

**Watch out:** by putting `rm -f` the files will be deleted without asking your confirmation

Answer (score 1):

You can try [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) solution

For example,these are files in folder

```
~/Test-folder$ ls *.txt -1
AB_DEFG17Sitanything.n.txt
AB_DEFG17SOManything.copy(2).txt
AB_DEFG17SOManything.nis.txt
AB_DEFG17SOManything.n.txt
AB_DEFG18SOManything.n.txt
AB_DEFG28SOManything.n.txt
AB_PIZG17SOManything.piz.txt
AB_PIZG28SOManything.n.txt
AB_PIZG76SOManything.n.txt
```

My code

```
import glob
r = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt") if "AB_DEFG" in f or "17" in f]
for f in r:
    print (f)
```

You will get

```
AB_DEFG17SOManything.n.txt
AB_DEFG17SOManything.nis.txt
AB_PIZG17SOManything.piz.txt
AB_DEFG17Sitanything.n.txt
AB_DEFG28SOManything.n.txt
AB_DEFG17SOManything.copy(2).txt
AB_DEFG18SOManything.n.txt
```

I forgot to add remove solution

```
import glob,os
r = [f for f in glob.glob("*.txt") if "AB_DEFG" in f or "17" in f]
for f in r:
    os.remove(f)
```

Only two files will stay

```
AB_PIZG28SOManything.n.txt
AB_PIZG76SOManything.n.txt
```