# Delete certain files from a directory using regex regarding a specific detail in file names

Tags: python, regex, match

Here I am making attempts to create a code which would delete files in a folder according to the mask. All files what include 17 should be removed and the general format of files in folder is ??_????17*.* where ? - Any symbol 1..n,A..z; * - any length of symbols; _ and 17 - are in any files (other files contain 18, as well) and its extension doesn't matter. Certain example of a files from folder: AB_DEFG17Something.Anything - Copy (2).txt; AB_DEFG18Something.Some - Copy (3).txt...
p.s. apologize for the previous insufficient and inexact explanation. You were right about globe.globe in case if files are named similarly. 
Would be glad to receive points of view about this task, I hope it will useful for someone else.

```
import os
import re

dir_name = "/Python/Test_folder"    # open the folder and read files
testfolder = os.listdir(dir_name)

def matching(r, s):                 # condition if there's nothing to match
    match = re.search(r, s)
    if match:
        return "Files don't exist!"

matching(r'^\w\w\[_]\w\w\w\w\[1]\[7]\w+\[.]\w+', testfolder)  # matching the mask of files

for item in testfolder.index(matching):
    if item.name(matching, s):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))

# format of filenames not converted :  ??_????17*.*
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question in a clearer way

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/9GXSbx/1

Comment: And why don't you use one of the answers provided [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365055/delete-certain-files-from-a-directory-using-regex-regarding-their-file-names) - with the exact same question from you???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete certain files from a directory using regex regarding their file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365055/delete-certain-files-from-a-directory-using-regex-regarding-their-file-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files in a folder with pattern `??_????17*.*` will be deleted with this code:

```
import os
import re

dir_name = "/Python/Test_folder"    # open the folder and read files
testfolder = os.listdir(dir_name)

p = re.compile(r'^[1-9\w]{2}_[1-9\w]{4}[1][7][\w]+\.[\w]+')
for each in testfolder:
    k = p.match(each)
    if k == None:
        continue
    os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, each))
```

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: `\d` is already included in `\w`, so `[\d\w]` is **exactly** the same than `\w`

Comment: @Toto well `\w` checks for `0-9` also. So you could replace `\d\w` with `\w`. Anyways both works perfectly. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Thx Toto and Theausome, you've forced me to learn and understand about regex more.